# Angular Root AppComponent methods NgOnit get executed twice when application starts

Tags: angular

I have a problem with Angular. It seems that when I use childroutes the main AppComponent get instanciated twice because the OnInit method is executed twice. I dont know If I configured the child routes wrong.

Here is my code :

**app-routing-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { AccueilComponent } from "./app/accueil/accueil.component";
import { AppComponent } from "./app/app.component";
import { AuthGuard } from "./app/auth/@guards/auth.guard";
import { LoginGuard } from "./app/auth/@guards/login.guard";
import { ChangePasswordComponent } from "./app/auth/change-password/change-password.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./app/auth/login/login.component";
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from "./app/page-not-found/page-not-found.component";
import { LoginResolverService } from './app/auth/@resolvers/login-resolver.service';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "ui/webconsult",
        component: AppComponent,
         children: [
            {
                path: "accueil",
                component: AccueilComponent,
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            },
            {
                path: "changePassword",
                component: ChangePasswordComponent,
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            },
            {
                path: "login",
                component: LoginComponent,
                canActivate: [LoginGuard],
               // resolve : { isIpBlocked : LoginResolverService }
            },
            { path: "", redirectTo: "accueil", pathMatch: "full" },
            { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent },
        ],
    }, 
    { path: "", redirectTo: "ui/webconsult", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent },
]; 


/**
 * app routing module
 */
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the default  angular CLI create index.html with `<app-root></app-root>` and add it to app.module.ts `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` , So after bootstrapping and initial app.component.ts in your routing module you load app.coponent again and initial it again.
You have many choices to solve this :

1. Remove app components from Routs ( and bootstrap app.components
   ass the default )
2. Create new component for bootstrapping

Answer (score 0):

Include `RouterModule` only in imports

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)]
})
```